# jmter constant video stream

Tags: video-streaming, jmeter, load-testing

I'm using Jmeter to load test a video stream, I can pass the login information but I need to have Jmeter "hold" at a page that serves up a video stream. How can I do this? I have cookie manager already set.

Answer (score 3):

1. If video stream doesn't live on your server you don't need to test it at all. For instance, if your site has YouTube frame you need to [exclude](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/exclude-external-site-td5717770.html) YouTube domain from embedded resources.
2. If video stream lives at your server - you can use [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) to request stream
3. If your page contains URL to video file it can be fetched via i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and [downloaded](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) as a regular file.

Comment: Can I specify how long to watch a stream for?

Comment: I'm trying to use method 2, though I'm not sure which TCP class name to use, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: As for now implemented classes are TCPClientImpl, BinaryTCPClientImpl and LengthPrefixedBinaryTCPClientImpl. Setting sampler execution time is not supported, however can be set via parent Runtime Controller. See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler and http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller for details

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure how the Runtime Controller will help. I just need to specify "Hey, Jmeter. Hold here and stream for X minutes/seconds".

Comment: I came across jsr223 sampler except I have no idea how to actually code this for ajax requests.

Comment: I came across using Selenium, it can login using one user/password and logout, but I want to use it with jmeter. I'm using Web Driver Sampler but jmeter is launching firefox as it's own profile and not my default one. I tried changing it but got: ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Firefox profile '3cu46o5w.default' named in system property 'webdriver.firefox.profile' not found. I am using a MAC.

Comment: You need to set profile name, not profile path. Open `profiles.ini` file, locate **Name** of your custom profile and provide it via webdriver.firefox.profile as it described here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jmeter-plugins/kgcOm80d-vY/4vXe24sruYEJ

Comment: hmm, I tried that. Name is set to default so I used that...same thing.

Comment: I used the chrome extension instead, that works. Almost there!!

Comment: I need jmeter to stay on a page for X seconds/minutes. I tried a loop but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: I did it. Had to combine Selenium, Jmeter, chromedriver and some Javascript. Whew. Thanks for the help!!